# MacOS MapKit - Drop pin at clicked location

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I want to make a basic app for MacOS which lets me drop a few pins and calculate travel time between them at a given speed (as the crow flies) but I'm struggling to add a pin at a mouse clicked location.

When I Ctrl + Click to add a pin the Y axis seems to be inverted. (I.e. if I click near the bottom of the map view the pin appears at the top). I also still want to be able to drag the map around with the mouse so I'm trying to use Ctrl + Click to drop a pin and then let the rest of the maps features work as normal by calling super.mouseDown, but it doesn't work (I.e. I'm not able to drag the map around when I don't hold Ctrl). Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent){
    if (event.modifierFlags.contains(.control)) {
        let location = mapView.convert(event.locationInWindow, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "test"
        annotation.subtitle = "subtest"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    } else {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `convert(_:toCoordinateFrom:)`: "Converts a point in the specified view’s coordinate system to a map coordinate.". Translate `locationInWindow` to the view’s coordinate system first.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now using `mapView.convert(event.locationInWindow, toCoordinateFrom: self.view)` which appears to be working. Any idea how to allow the map to be navigated with the moue when not holding Ctrl? `super.mouseDown` doesn't work.

Comment: Solved it. I had another view overlapping most of the map view lol.